# Spring Boot RestTemplate setErrorHandler and Timeout exceptions

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a use case while using restTemplate where I don't want restTemplate to throw exceptions when the response includes bad http codes like 400, 500, 404 etc, so I am using `setErrorHandler` as below:

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
            protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
                return false;
            }});
```

But will this also eat up any connection/socket/read timeout exceptions, if yes is there a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In case of an exception processing the HTTP request, an exception of
>   the type RestClientException will be thrown; this behavior can be
>   changed by plugging in another ResponseErrorHandler implementation
>   into the RestTemplate.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-resttemplate